# What should be the input shape for ConvLSTM1D

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-science

I have a time-series dataset which is having 10000 samples and 50 features, I want to use ConvLSTM for prediction for that I am using TensorFlow for implementation but I am getting the below error

```
Input 0 of layer "conv_lstm1d_10" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 1, 10000)
```

The model that I have made is below

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,len(df[features]))),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'),
    ]
)
```

I am confused now with the input size so let me know what should be the input size.

Comment: what is the shape of x_train?

Comment: Why do you want to use a Conv1DLSTM, since you do not have a sequence of 1D Images? Use a plain LSTM.

Comment: shape of x_train is (10000, 50)

Comment: I read one paper where they have used convlstm for timeseries data so want to implement and check it

Comment: Conv1DLSTM can only be applied to certain kinds of time series data (Sequence of 1D images), you don't even seem to have time series data, your data should have shape (samples, timesteps, features).